# Discrete uniform distribution on a finite set

Tags: self-study, distributions, uniform-distribution

I have a random variable Y which has a discrete uniform distribution on the set {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

I have to find the following:

i) Find P(Y)

ii) P($Y^2$)?

iii) E($Y^2$)

Answers:

The first one's quite easy I guess. Since P(Y) = $\frac{1}{N}$, I got $\frac{1}{10}$ for that.

I'm not sure for the second one. Is it $\frac{1}{5}$? If I square all the terms of X I'll have that N=5. And the third question follows up from the second.

Need someone to verify this.

Comment: Please check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and edit your question appropriately

Comment: What is "X" and what exactly do you mean by "P(Y)"?  The entire probability function?

Comment: @whuber the X there is supposed to be a Y (edited) and yes, it's the probability function.

Comment: A specification of a function should state where it takes what values, not just its value when it isn't zero (at least the very least not without an indication of where that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is self-study I can only supply hints.  Yes, $P(Y=-5)=P(Y=-4)=\cdots=P(Y=5)=1/10$.  Think of $Y^2$ as a transformation. Although the only possible values for $Y^2$ are 1,4,9,16 and 25, do you think they all have the same probability?

Now once you have the answer to ii) you can get iii) by summing
$iP(Y^2=i)$ for each $i$.